# Why in this case the stdin fd is not ready

Tags: c++, linux, scanf, polling, epoll

According to [Linux Programmer's Manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html), `poll` can wait for one of a set of file descriptors to become ready to perform I/O.

According to my understanding, if I add `POLLIN` to `events`, `poll` will return with a `> 0` integer, when there is at least one fd which is ready to be read.

Consider the following code, In this code, I want the program echos my input immediately after I typed the character `\n`.

```
int main(){
    char buffer[maxn];
    while (true) {
        struct pollfd pfd[1];
        std::memset(pfd, 0, sizeof pfd);

        pfd[0].fd = STDIN_FILENO;
        pfd[0].events = POLLIN;

        int ret = poll(pfd, 1, 1000);

        if (ret < 0) {
        }
        else if (ret == 0) {
        }
        else {
            if ((pfd[0].revents & POLLIN) == POLLIN) {
                int n;
                n = fscanf(stdin, "%s", &buffer);
                if(n > 0){
                    printf("data from stdin: %s\n", buffer);
                }
            }else if((pfd[1].revents & POLLHUP) == POLLHUP){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I type

```
aa bb cc dd
```

I thought `fscanf` hasn't retrieved all data from stdin, because it only reads `aa`. So when the loop restarts, stdin's fd should still be ready. As a consequence, `(pfd[0].revents & POLLIN) == POLLIN` still stands, so I thought we can see the following output

```
data from stdin: aa
data from stdin: bb
data from stdin: cc
data from stdin: dd
```

However, actually only the **first** line is printed. I got strange here, I think this is similar with `epoll`'s [Edge-triggered mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt#Edge-triggered). However, `poll` is level-triggered.

So can you explain why this happens with `fscanf`?

Comment: Mixing buffered I/O and file descriptors looks like tricky business.  What happens if you avoid the buffered I/O, and only use file descriptor based APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polling works at the file *descriptor* level while `fscanf` works at the higher file *handle* level.

At the higher level, the C runtime library is free to cache the input stream in such a way that it would affect what you can see at the lower level.

For example (and this is probably what's happening here), the first time you `fscanf` your word `aa`, the entire *line* is read from the file descriptor and cached, before that first word is handed back to you.

A subsequent `fscanf` (with no intervening `poll`) would first check the cache to get the next word and, if it weren't there, it would go back to the file descriptor to get more input.

Unfortunately, the fact that you're checking for a poll event before doing this is causing problems. As far as the file *descriptor* level goes, the *entire* line has been read by your first `fscanf` so no further input is available - `poll` will therefore wait until such information *does* become available.

You can see this in action if you change:

```
n = fscanf(stdin, "%s", buffer);
```

into:

```
n = read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, 3);
```

and change the `printf` to:

```
printf("data from stdin: %*.*s\n", n, n, buffer);
```

In that case, you *do* get the output you expect as soon as you press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key:

```
data from stdin: aa
data from stdin: bb
data from stdin: cc
data from stdin: dd
```

Just keep in mind that sample code is reading up to *three* characters (like `aa<space>`) rather than a word. It's more to illustrate what the problem is rather than give you the solution (to match your question "Can you explain *why* this happens?").

The *solution* is not to mix descriptor and handle based I/O when the caching of the latter can affect the former.